# Plotting several Datasets in Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I just want to plot some data in Recharts with react.

Its really cool but there is one Problem. It only allows to plot one dataset not any further datasets. Do you know how can I accomplish this? Maybe another Framework which is quite simple and nice too:)

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Recharts allows you to model many datasets. Do you have a specific type of graph (with data) you'd like to use recharts for?

Comment: Its been while a question is asked can you please tell me about how you achieved it. As I am facing the same issue. Thanks in advance.